# Не получается разобраться в голосовой библиотеке Sphinx Java

Tags: java, sphinx

Скачал библиотеку, закинул все в src. Для теста установил главный класс на демо Dialog. Но после запуска выбивают ошибки.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.SaxLoader.load(SaxLoader.java:71)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.<init>(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:59)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:45)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer.<init>(AbstractSpeechRecognizer.java:44)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer.<init>(LiveSpeechRecognizer.java:34)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.dialog.DialogDemo.main(DialogDemo.java:140)
/Users/KLASTER/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 0 секунд)
```

В рунете нет похожих тем(по крайней мере я не нашел). На англ.сайтах добыл инфу , что проблема в расположении xml файла. Но решить проблему не удалось. Буду благодарен за помощь в освоении библиотеки!

```
package edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.dialog;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;


public class DialogDemo {

private static final String ACOUSTIC_MODEL =
    "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us";
private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH =
    "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict";
private static final String GRAMMAR_PATH =
    "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/dialog/";
private static final String LANGUAGE_MODEL =
    "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/dialog/weather.lm";

private static final Map<String, Integer> DIGITS =
    new HashMap<String, Integer>();

static {
    DIGITS.put("oh", 0);
    DIGITS.put("zero", 0);
    DIGITS.put("one", 1);
    DIGITS.put("two", 2);
    DIGITS.put("three", 3);
    DIGITS.put("four", 4);
    DIGITS.put("five", 5);
    DIGITS.put("six", 6);
    DIGITS.put("seven", 7);
    DIGITS.put("eight", 8);
    DIGITS.put("nine", 9);
}

private static double parseNumber(String[] tokens) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
        if (tokens[i].equals("point"))
            sb.append(".");
        else
            sb.append(DIGITS.get(tokens[i]));
    }

    return Double.parseDouble(sb.toString());
}
private static void recognizeDigits(LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer) {
    System.out.println("Digits recognition (using GrXML)");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Example: one two three");
    System.out.println("Say \"101\" to exit");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    recognizer.startRecognition(true);
    while (true) {
        String utterance = recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();
        if (utterance.equals("one zero one")
            || utterance.equals("one oh one"))
            break;
        else
            System.out.println(utterance);
    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();
}

private static void recognizerBankAccount(LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer) {
    System.out.println("This is bank account voice menu");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Example: balance");
    System.out.println("Example: withdraw zero point five");
    System.out.println("Example: deposit one two three");
    System.out.println("Example: back");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");

    double savings = .0;
    recognizer.startRecognition(true);

    while (true) {
        String utterance = recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();
        if (utterance.endsWith("back")) {
            break;
        } else if (utterance.startsWith("deposit")) {
            double deposit = parseNumber(utterance.split("\\s"));
            savings += deposit;
            System.out.format("Deposited: $%.2f\n", deposit);
        } else if (utterance.startsWith("withdraw")) {
            double withdraw = parseNumber(utterance.split("\\s"));
            savings -= withdraw;
            System.out.format("Withdrawn: $%.2f\n", withdraw);
        } else if (!utterance.endsWith("balance")) {
            System.out.println("Unrecognized command: " + utterance);
        }

        System.out.format("Your savings: $%.2f\n", savings);
    }

    recognizer.stopRecognition();
}

private static void recognizeWeather(LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer) {
    System.out.println("Try some forecast. End with \"the end\"");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Example: mostly dry some fog patches tonight");
    System.out.println("Example: sunny spells on wednesday");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

    recognizer.startRecognition(true);
    while (true) {
        String utterance = recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();
        if (utterance.equals("the end"))
            break;
        else
            System.out.println(utterance);
    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath(ACOUSTIC_MODEL);
    configuration.setDictionaryPath(DICTIONARY_PATH);
    configuration.setGrammarPath(GRAMMAR_PATH);
    configuration.setUseGrammar(true);

    configuration.setGrammarName("dialog");
    LiveSpeechRecognizer jsgfRecognizer =
        new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

    configuration.setGrammarName("digits.grxml");
    LiveSpeechRecognizer grxmlRecognizer =
        new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

    configuration.setUseGrammar(false);
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath(LANGUAGE_MODEL);
    LiveSpeechRecognizer lmRecognizer =
        new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

    jsgfRecognizer.startRecognition(true);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Choose menu item:");
        System.out.println("Example: go to the bank account");
        System.out.println("Example: exit the program");
        System.out.println("Example: weather forecast");
        System.out.println("Example: digits\n");

        String utterance = jsgfRecognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();

        if (utterance.startsWith("exit"))
            break;

        if (utterance.equals("digits")) {
            jsgfRecognizer.stopRecognition();
            recognizeDigits(grxmlRecognizer);
            jsgfRecognizer.startRecognition(true);
        }

        if (utterance.equals("bank account")) {
            jsgfRecognizer.stopRecognition();
            recognizerBankAccount(jsgfRecognizer);
            jsgfRecognizer.startRecognition(true);
        }

        if (utterance.endsWith("weather forecast")) {
            jsgfRecognizer.stopRecognition();
            recognizeWeather(lmRecognizer);
            jsgfRecognizer.startRecognition(true);
        }
    }

    jsgfRecognizer.stopRecognition();
}
}
```

IDE NetBeans, перед выполнение указал этот файл как главный класс. Этот код из примера библиотеки.Все что было внутри файла, закинул в src.

Comment: Приложите пример запускаемого кода

Comment: Добавил запускаемый код.

Comment: Буду рад помощи по освоению библиотеки.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Необходимо скачать **jar файлы**, и закинуть их как библиотеки. И запустить демо. Если засунуть папки с кодом в src, будет ругаться на пути.